# How to disable React link and function if link points to current active "page"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a navigation component with a list containing links. I need to run a function when these are clicked in addition to linking(going to specific page). What I have so far is working except if user clicks on link to active page.

How can I modify my code so my function doesn't run and link is disable if user is already on that page?

Here is what I have:

```
    class HeaderMenu extends Component {

      navFunc = () => {
        //some functionality
      }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="sidebar">
          <ul className="header">
            <li onClick={this.navFunc}>
              <Link href="/index">
                <a>home</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li onClick={this.navFunc}>
              <Link href="/about">
                <a>about</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li onClick={this.navFunc}>
              <Link href="/other">
                <a>other</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: One way is by using state. How is the current page defined, and what component is it rendered in? Are you using a routing library?

Comment: I'm using next.js for routing. How would I use state?

Comment: you might want to consider a routing library that isn't so minimal. you can definitely just `window.location` your way to a solution here, but other routing libraries give you urls, url params and queries as props.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `ActiveLink` component that will skip the push action when clicked.

This `ActiveLink` component is based on the example in the [next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter) (scroll up to see it), and I have not tested it.

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'

const ActiveLink = ({ children, router, href }) => {
  const active = router.pathname === href

  const style = {
    marginRight: 10,
    color: active ? 'red' : 'black'
  }

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    active || router.push(href)
  }

  return (
    <a href={href} onClick={handleClick} style={style}>
      {children}
    </a>
  )
}

export default withRouter(ActiveLink)
```

Comment: The link on the post seems wrong, use [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter) instead.

Comment: Updated the link